# Why does my table get duplicated every time button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a simple website, where you can choose a option. I did that with `<select>`. When an option is chosen and the user clicks the button a single table should appear. But when I press the button many times, an additional table will appear for each time you click on the button.

```js
    var prijsi = 19.99;
    var kwartaal = prijsi * 3;
    var jaar = prijsi * 12;
    var contract = prijsi * 24;
    var prijst = 30.99;
    var prijskw = prijst * 3;
    var prijsjaar = prijst * 12;
    var prijscontract = prijst * 24;
    var prijsa = 50.99;
    var prijsakw = prijsa * 3;
    var prijsajaar = prijsa * 12;
    var prijsacontract = prijsa * 24;
    var extratela = prijsa + 1;
    var extratelkw = (3*1) + prijsakw;
    var extrateljaar = (12*1) + prijsajaar;
    var extratelcontract = (24*1) + prijsacontract;
    var extratelt = prijst + 1;
    var extrateltj = (1*12) + prijsjaar;
    var extratkw = (3*1) + prijskw;
    var extratc = (24*1) + prijscontract;

    function kostenBerekenen(){
        pakket = document.getElementById('pakket').value;
        if(pakket == ""){
         document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML+=("Kies een pakket!");
        }
        else if(pakket == 'internet')
        {
            document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML+=("<table border='0' id='kosten'><thead colspan='2'><th>Kosten</th></thead><tr><td>Kosten per maand: &euro;" + prijsi + 
            '</td></tr><tr><td>Kosten per kwartaal: ' +' &euro;' + kwartaal + 
            '</td></tr><tr><td>Kosten per jaar: ' + '&euro;' + jaar + '</td></tr><tr><td>Kosten per contract (24 maanden): &euro;' + contract + '</td></tr></table>');
        }
        else if(pakket == 'telefonie'){
         document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML+=("<table border='0' id='kosten'><thead colspan='2'><th>Kosten</th></thead><tr><td>Kosten per maand: &euro;" + prijst + 
            '</td></tr><tr><td>Kosten per kwartaal: ' +' &euro;' + prijskw + 
            '</td></tr><tr><td>Kosten per jaar: ' + '&euro;' + prijsjaar + '</td></tr><tr><td>Kosten per contract (24 maanden): &euro;' + prijscontract + 
            '</td></tr><tr><td>Kosten p/maand met <strong>extra telefoon:</strong> &euro;' + extratelt +  '</td></tr><tr><td>Kosten per kwartaal met <strong>extra telefoon:</strong> &euro;' + extratkw + 
            '</td></tr><tr><td>Kosten per jaar met <strong>extra telefoon:</strong> &euro;' + extrateltj.toFixed(2) + '</td></tr><tr><td>Kosten per standaard contract(24maanden) met <strong>extra telefoon:</strong> &euro;' + 
            extratc + '</table>');
        }
        else{
         document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML+=("<table border='0' id='kosten'><thead colspan='2'><th>Kosten</th></thead><tr><td>Kosten per maand: &euro;" + prijsa + 
            '</td></tr><tr><td>Kosten per kwartaal: ' +' &euro;' + prijsakw + 
            '</td></tr><tr><td>Kosten per jaar: ' + '&euro;' + prijsajaar + '</td></tr><tr><td>Kosten per contract (24 maanden): &euro;' + prijsacontract + '</td></tr>' + 
            '<tr><td>Kosten p/maand met <Strong>extra telefoon:</strong> &euro;' + extratela +  '</td></tr><tr><td>Kosten per kwartaal met <strong>extra telefoon:</strong> &euro;' + extratelkw + 
            '</td></tr><tr><td>Kosten per jaar met <strong>extra telefoon:</strong> &euro;' + extrateljaar + '</td></tr><tr><td>Kosten per standaard contract(24maanden) met <strong>extra telefoon:</strong> &euro;' + extratelcontract + '</table>');
        }
    };
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>   
    <html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="helpdeskafdeling" name="description">
        <meta content="problemen, internet, internet problemen, helpen, helpdesk"
        name="keywords">
        <meta content="Tayfun Kayahan" name="author">
    
        <title>Wat kost het | IDC Solutions</title>
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='images/favicon.ico' />
        <!--<script src='javascripts/kosten.js'></script>-->
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <header>
                <hgroup>
                    <h1><img alt="logo" id="solution" src="images/solution.png">
                    IDC Solutions</h1>
                </hgroup>
    
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
    
                        <li>
                            <a href="helpdeskafdeling.html">Klantenservice</a>
                        </li>
    
                        <li>
                            <a href="bundels.html">Bundels</a>
                        </li>
    
                        <li>
                            <a href="about.html">Over ons</a>
                        </li>
    
                        <li>
                            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
    
        <div id="info">
            <h2>Bereken hier al uw kosten</h2><img id=
            "telefoon" src="images/telefoon.png"> <img id="internet" src=
            "images/internet.png">
            <br/>
            <Br/>
      
      <td><Strong>Kies uw bundel : </Strong></td>
       <select id="pakket">
        <option value="">Kies uw bundel</option>
        <option value="internet">Internet</option>
        <option value="telefonie">Telefonie</option>
        <option value="allin">All-in-1</option>
       </select>
       <button id="bereken" value="bereken" onclick='kostenBerekenen();'>Bereken uw Kosten!</button>
      <div id="resultaat"></div>
        </div>
    
        <footer>
            <small>&copy;Tayfun Kayahan | IDC Solutions | 1e Jaars student te ID
            College Zoetermeer | Online Helpdesk | 1011176 |</small>
        </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you put your codes on JSFiddle, please?

Comment: There's no jQuery in your code.

Comment: @Karmacoma A Stack Snippet works equally well here, since there are no external dependencies (aside from some missing images that don't prevent an answer from being given).

Comment: @Tayfun For future reference, this is the blog post that explains how Stack Snippets work: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending the table each time the user clicks. Use this:

`document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML= ...`

Instead of this:

`document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML+= ...`

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this..

```
function kostenBerekenen(){
    document.getElementById('resultaat').innerHTML = ''; //insert this statement 
    pakket = document.getElementById('pakket').value;
   /* other...*/
}
```